# What is the cheapest way to get from South America to Australia?

Tags: budget, planning, australia, south-america

What is the cheapest way to get from South America to Australia?

I found several flights mostly from Buenos Aires and Santiago de Chile, however the prices are quite prohibitive. Do you recommend any alternatives? My journey time is not time limited.

- How to find cheapest flights beside hunting on Qantas/Air New Zealand promotions
- Any ferry service?
- Using a freight ship - any opinions? Not very cheap, but comparable to some air tickets.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/598/where-can-i-get-information-on-freighter-travel

Comment: I don't know if ocean-going ferries are common anywhere in the world! (-:

Comment: You got me @hippietrail :)

Comment: Guess, Chile is the best option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Living in New Zealand and having had quite a lot of looks at flights to and from South America - for direct flights you have two options really - LATAM  and Aerolineas Argentinas.  LAN is more expensive but more reliable, and AA is ... the budget option.  It was fine tho to fly with, once they actually took off.  When they took off.

There are sometimes 'cheap' routes via LAX, Mexico City and down, or LAX, Houston and then down as well.