# Is it possible to accompany a live animal (dog) during air travel (cargo)?

Tags: air-travel, transportation, pets

I would like to transport AVI cargo (live animal - dog) from Melbourne, Australia (MEL) to London, UK (LHR), via air travel, ideally direct.

The crate will need to be accompanied by an attendant (myself). The dog cannot travel separately (by itself) in the hold on a passenger plan or on a cargo plane.

Edit: my dog is too large/heavy to travel accompanied in the cabin, which is why I am looking at cargo airlines (and because no one can access the cargo hold during passenger airline flights).

I know it is possible for a groom/attendant to accompany animals such as horses or rare/zoo animals when they travel as freight. Does anyone know if this can be arranged for dogs? E.g. Are there any cargo (or passenger) airlines that will allow an attendant to accompany a dog travelling in a crate? (Including either companies/airlines that work directly with private individuals or through pet transport agents)

I saw on another question thread that it is possible in some circumstances for people to travel on cargo planes: [Is it possible to travel on cargo airplanes?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14297/is-it-possible-to-travel-on-cargo-airplanes) - but does anyone know which airlines allow attendants to accompany live animals? (as mentioned in the answer to the question)

Comment: Here are the [guidelines for bringing a pet into the UK](https://www.gov.uk/take-pet-abroad) including the [approved list of carriers and entry points](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/pet-travel-approved-air-sea-rail-and-charter-routes-for-the-movement-of-pets/approved-air-routes-for-pet-travel). [Australia does not allow pets in the cabin](http://www.dogjaunt.com/guides/international-airline-pet-policies-for-in-cabin-travel/)

Comment: What do you mean by accompanying?  Do you need to be physically with the animal all the time?  Freighters have some seats near the cockpit, but sitting back in the cargo area through out the flight is unlikely, as containers and freight could shift during turbulence.  Race horses travel in specially designed aircraft not on general cargo flights.

Comment: Since it is an Australian government regulation which does not allow pets in the cabin, you might want to explore Australian pet transporters such as  [JetPets](http://www.jetpets.com.au/) to discuss your options, such as a short flight to a destination which allows in-cabin pets (e.g., NZ). The pet transport companies also make flight arrangements for the human companion.

Comment: @pnuts - Yes my dog is 23kg so there aren't any passenger airlines that allow dogs of that size to travel in the cabin. That is why I am looking at cargo airlines, which often have attendants accompanying live animals (though I haven't yet heard of dogs).

Comment: @Tom - my dog would need to be accompanied in the same way horses and other rare/special animals (such as zoo animals) are sometimes accompanied by attendants/grooms on cargo flights, when they need to be checked regularly. I would need to be able to check on my dog fairly frequently, so would at least need access to wherever the crate was stored.

I am mainly just trying to find out which airlines it is that allow attendants/grooms to accompany live animals, and I will then approach them to see if they would consider a dog.

Comment: @Dorothy - I have spoken with JetPets about some options, but they work with passenger airlines and arrange for pets to travel in the cargo hold - which no one can access during the flight. My dog is too big (23kg) to be able to travel in the cabin on any airline. My understanding is that the Australian regulations in regards to animals travelling in cabins relate to passenger aircraft, not cargo aircraft. So I am mainly just trying to find out which cargo airlines it is that allow attendants/grooms to accompany live animals, and I will then approach them to see if they would consider a dog.

Comment: We should move this into chat... Any possibility of your dog being classified as a service animal? Example [Virgin Australia](https://www.virginaustralia.com/us/en/plan/special-needs-assistance/travelling-with-an-assistance-dog/)

Comment: Why can't your dog travel alone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about permanently relocating a dog, which better suits for Expats.SE

Comment: @JonathanReez - I didn't realise there was an expats stack exchange. However doesn't transportation methods fit better into travel? Also the relocation isn't permanent.

Comment: Why do you need the dog during your time as a tourist? Is it a service dog? Travel.SE is focused on questions about stays shorter than 3-6 months.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I have kind of [stopped asking this kind of questions](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2484392/Travel-firm-offering-package-holidays--stuffed-TOYS-Japanese-company-send-teddy-bears-backpacking-photograph-famous-landmarks.html).

Comment: If this is possible at all, you should probably be prepared for it to be incredibly expensive.

Answer (score 9):

The majority of dogs and small animals are shipped in a special section of the lower cargo hold, which can be climate controlled better than the rest of the cargo hold.  This area is not open for human travel, as it has no seats or seat belts, no bathrooms, no windows, no communication and no easy access to the rest of the plane.

The pallet area on the top deck does not have a lot of space to allow people to walk around the pallets.  While in theory your dog could be loaded in the foremost container, due to liability and safety issues the chance of being allowed in the cargo bay as a non-employee is basically zero.

As I mentioned in my comment, horses are transported in specially designed planes which are chartered by horse owners, race organizers, etc. These planes have compartments for horses and seating for trainers/groomers. Horses do not fly on standard cargo flights.

Other rare animals, zoo animals, etc would likely travel by private charter likely in a cage designed specifically for that animal and with proper seats for staff.

Short of chartering your own plane, your best bet is a series of short flights, so that you have access to your dog at the stop over cities.

Comment: Horses are transported in normal cargo planes, but they are transported in specially designed cargo crates (called airstables) and are accompanied by caretakers called flying grooms. However, during the flight, the caretakers do not enter the cargo hold. Instead the horses are secured, provided hay and water and to avoid turbulence stallions are loaded at the front of the aircraft, and mares at the back. Although rare, but if required, they can also be sedated and most such cargo flights also have a qualified vet on board.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - There are also special horse transport planes, such as those from Sutton Transport.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your answer! I've been looking into the services that Emirates SkyCargo offers, which seem to include 'attendants on request' for horses and 'sensitive animals'. They state "No matter what your animal is, we offer special arrangements designed to meet every need with animal welfare on our mind" - while I'm assuming this probably applies more to exotic pets, zoo animals, etc, I can't see why special arrangements couldn't also be made for dogs, if it is available for these other species. I am wondering if this sort of special arrangement is unheard of for dogs..?

Comment: @hannah did you ever find out? What solution did you use?