# Travel from Canada to Mexico without American Visa

Tags: usa, canada, transportation, mexico

I'm from Iran. I'm already in Canada with a Student Visa, I'm planing to go to Mexico for new year holidays. I live in Vancouver Island. with below conditions:

1. I don't want to enter US because it needs visa and It takes a long time.
2. I don't want to flight to Mexico because it is very expensive
3. Is there any way to go via Ocean from Vancouver Island to Mexico?
4. Is there any thing like hitchhike in boats and ships?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Do you have somewhere specific in Mexico that you want to visit?

Comment: It should only take 2 or 3 weeks to get a US tourist or transit visa. The real problem with is that it is expensive (US$160) compared to the short 90-day validity for Iranian nationals.

Comment: @GregHewgill , no, i just want to visit mexico

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, through regularly scheduled means of transportation, flying is likely to be the cheapest option for you.

Sites like [kayak](http://kayak.com) might help you reduce the price, and you can specify direct flights, skipping out the US.

You can look at things like [freighter travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/598/where-can-i-get-information-on-freighter-travel), where you use a cargo ship to get down, but otherwise your only other 'hitchhiking' option is to look at a website like [findacrew.net](http://www.findacrew.net), where you can look for boats going to Mexico, and maybe you can help out onboard in exchange for a ride.