# Travel to Faroe Island by cargo ship

Tags: denmark, freighter-travel, faroe-islands

A while ago I met a person who claimed to have traveled from Denmark to Faroe Island on a cargo ship.

Is this really possible? How could I find a ship that could host me?

Comment: Possible? Certainly. But perhaps he works for the shipping compamy...

Comment: Sometimes cargo ship allow passengers, maybe ask : https://www.faroeship.com/

Comment: @xuq01 I'm pretty sure he doesn't.

Comment: @Max Thanks for the link! I will give it a try! :)

Comment: You are aware that there are is a regular passenger ferry service between Denmark and the Faroe Islands? That option is likely both cheaper and more convenient than trying to find a cargo ship allowing you to travel.

Comment: In any case, you can google, there are various websites that allow you to book into cargo ships: it is a niche market. It is not so cheap, and some people love it, but you need a lot of flexibility: you never know when the ship will really sail.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Ok, I was not aware of that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's entirely possible that it was on the [Smyril Line's Norröna](http://www.smyrilline.com/norrona/info-about-the-ship) - a cargo ship come passenger vessel, and the only one going to the Faroes.  It has a cargo capacity of 3,250 tonnes.

Failing that, we have [another question with detailed information on how to get onboard cargo ships as a passenger](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/598/where-can-i-get-information-on-freighter-travel).

Comment: Where do you get "cargo ship come passenger vessel" from? It seems to have been [built specifically for Smyril Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Norr%C3%B6na) and sure _looks_ like a purpose-built cruiseferry.

Comment: From the very page I linked to - "Passenger and freight ship" (scroll down)

Comment: x @Mark: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I understood "cargo ship come passenger vessel" to be a claim that it was originally a cargo ship and was later modified to take passengers. But the page you link to says it has carried both from the beginning. Perhaps an English problem?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think I understand the confusion, but I'm not sure how to confirm more than the site has either :/ Still the OP seems happy.