# West Coast, US to S Korea by sea with cat, economy

Tags: south-korea, sea-travel, pets, freighter-travel, international-waters

I want to travel to South Korea from California/Oregon/West Coast by boat with my cat. I'm not looking for luxury as it's just a focused trip to get from point A to point B without flying. Travel duration is flexible but I'm hoping for something less than 3 weeks. I've been researching cargo boats, but I'm having trouble figuring out if they allow people (or pets).

Anyone with a little more knowledge or experience that can point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know a guy who's doing a cruise from Seattle to Tokyo (so not quite South Korea) in October.  15 days I think he said.  Unsure if you can take cat though ‍♂️

Comment: @Midavalo, could you find out which cruise line?

Comment: [Norwegian Cruise Lines](https://www.ncl.com/) - it's on their website, just search Destination Tokyo and Departure Seattle ([sample search](https://www.ncl.com/vacations?cruise-port=sea&port-of-call=tok&sort=price_low_high))

Comment: Thanks for the lead, but no cats allowed (on most cruise lines).

Comment: There are some potential leads in [Freighter Cruises Worldwide](http://cruisepeople.co.uk/freighters.htm)

Comment: Freighters do take passengers, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/598/where-can-i-get-information-on-freighter-travel I am 99% sure they don't accept pets, though.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to take a boat rather than fly there?